# Problem with adding TestSubResult via Azure devops restAPI 6.0-preview.1

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to add TestSubResult to TestResult. I was successfully added attachments to TestResults. but when i try add TestSubResult there is testSubResultID parameter. I dont have any idea on how to get this TestSubResult ID. Also this is an automated test result

Using
POST [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/Results/{testCaseResultId}/attachments?testSubResultId={testSubResultId}&api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/test/Runs/%7BrunId%7D/Results/%7BtestCaseResultId%7D/attachments?testSubResultId=%7BtestSubResultId%7D&api-version=6.0-preview.1)

with the post body params

```
public class TestSubResultRequest
{
    public string AttachmentType { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Stream { get; set; }
}
```

I tried with a random number in place of testSubResultId, but it exited the line without showing any error and ended the execution of the program.

Answer (score 0):

During my test, you could found the id in the ui.

[Attachments - Get Test Sub Result Attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/get-test-sub-result-attachments?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

[image]

Comment: If I understood correctly that will be the TestResultID and it usually starts with 100000.